# align 2 span with text number

Tags: html, css, flexbox

in this case i try to align span with own text but i can not do this with flex box.
i show inspect in image and you can see there that they are not align with each other.

note: vertical align not working!

[image]

you can  acually see that right number is upper than left one.

```
        <div class="slide-body">

      <div class="body-price">
        <span class="price">499000</span>
        <span class="price-off">45%</span>
      </div>

      <p class="main-price">900000</p>
      
    </div>

  .slide-body {
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
}

.body-price {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;

  padding-inline: .5rem;
}
```

Comment: `align-items: center;` is sufficient to do what you are asking. If it is not accurate then something else in your code is causing the misalignment. You should create a snippet in your quetsion that demonstrates the issue instead of a picture.

Comment: i do not have any cascading code, all my code is here.

Comment: The code you provided isn't enough to diagnose your specific issue. Try to recreate the issue in a snippet and see if it is still present.

Comment: maybe you should play around with `padding-inline` to get wanted result. It might affect your positioning